# RewriteCond not working - Removing blog from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched through like 15 stackoverflow questions and searched/read [Phile](https://github.com/PhileCMS) docs, and I'm not sure why I'm having an issue.  I'm using Phile and I've got a /blog-folder/ where all of my posts are going to go. I'm trying to remove the /blog-folder/ from the post URLs -- right now they are example.com/blog-folder/post and I just want example.com/post.

This is my current .htaccess without caching stuff

```
#####################################
# Redirect stuff
#####################################
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Enable URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /blog-folder/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
#####################################
# disable dir
#####################################
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having problem of using same condition for multiple rule.

Try it like this I am assuming everything is handled by index.php file which resides in blog-folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ blog-folder/index.php [NC,L]
```

Now access it by `example.com/post` it will rewritten to index.php which is handling the request.

Comment: This breaks and  gives a 500 Internal Server Error -- there is no index.php in the folder, there is only an index.php at the root.

Comment: Then what is blog-folder doing? because according to your rule every request is rewritten to index.php then it is not possible to use the same condition to rewrite to blog-folder directory.

Comment: I just realized that folders in phile have an index.md file in them. The Phile structure looks like this http://philecms.com/docs.html

Comment: Where are your project file resides and what is inside in blog-folder can you explain?

Comment: All Phile core folders are located at the root of my domain /. Phile reads markdown files (file.md) and uses Twig for templating. So, every post, page, and category is a file.md. Files are located wherever they are found in the file structure. So if there is a folder /blog-post/ then any file.md located in that folder will be at /blog-post/file. You don't have to have a index.md file in a folder, but to access /folder/ it needs an index.md. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, Currently I don't have the knowledge of Philecms but what I think is that most of the cms have front controller which is index.php file so what I suggest that remove every rule related to blog-folder spare index.php file rules and then try to access.

Comment: The only other stuff in the htaccess file that I listed in the question are caching details.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier then you  expected just follow this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.blog-f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.blog[L]
```

Comment: This gives me "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." -- Also, my blog folder is called /item-name/ if that is different (having a "-")

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog-folder/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Should leave you with the URL: `example.com/post`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing.

Comment: I tried that earlier today, and its still giving me /blog-folder/post. Cleared cache, tested in multiple browsers.